# How to declare STL Set with comparison Object of class with parametrized constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

When using the set, I want to pass my own comparison function which also takes a parameter. How to do that and how to pass that set as reference to other functions?

For example, I've Comparator Class (with `operator()` overloaded and private default constructor) which takes an argument in constructor which is used while doing comparison. which works fine with sort algorithms like,

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), Comparator(10));
```

but how do I declare a set with this comparator object with parameter.

I've tried these syntax's,

```
std::set< MyObj, bool(*)(const MyObj&, const MyObj&)>   myObjSet(Compatrator(100));
```

Now when I insert as, `myObjSet.insert(MyObj(0))`, it gives error as `Error: "left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union"`

Now when I declare set as,

```
std::set< MyObj, Comparator(int)> myObjSet;
```

it gives error as "function returning function".

---

```
class Comparator
{
    int m_cmpParameter;
    Comparator();

public:

    ~Comparator();
    Comparator(int pCmpParam):m_cmpParameter(pCmpParam){}

    bool operator()(const MyObj& pObjA, const MyObj& pObjB);
};
```

---

In my project I've this one class for all comparisons required by STL containers. How do I use this Comparator class with Set with passing a parameter to comparison object?
And How do I pass this set as reference to other functions, more specifically, what should be the function signature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a parameter in your comparator, you'll need to use a function object. Something along the lines of your class. I think you'll need to make the function call operator a `const` member. You'd use it something like this:

```
std::set<MyObj, Comparator> myObjSet(Comparator(100));
```

Comment: Specifically, you'll have to construct the comparison object that you want to use and pass that to the set constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Kuhl and Mr. Clow. Acc. to me also its the obvious solution which I've tried before putting this question and, Believe me, It was giving error. After your answer I became confident the there is some other problem which I found out this morning. Actually the syntax of my comparator constructor is, **Comparator(CompareType pCmpType)**, where CompareType is enum. Now when I create set as **std::set<MyObj, Comparator> myObjSet(Comparator(kCompareType_area));**, and while inserting, **myObjSet.insert(123)** it gives error as, _left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union_

Comment: But when I create set object like, **std::set<MyObj, Comparator> myObjSet(Comparator((CompareType)kCompareType_area))**, it compiles just fine. And now I am easily passing my set as reference also, So the solution is to explicitly provide the datatype of enum while declearing the set with comparator object.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @BitKnight: you should have posted the complete and _actual_ code! The issue you describe is the [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): when the constructor argument happens to be an identifier the statement meant to be an object definition can also be interpreted as a function declaration and the compiler prefers the latter. That is not the case when the argument is an integer literal as you posted in your question! The usual fix is using extra parenthesis or, with C++11 or later curlies.

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. I didn't know this _Most Vexing Parse_ concept. Thanks a lot for enlightening me on this. It never occurred to me that this could be the problem, may be that is why I posted the simplest form of my problem. I'll surely post complete and actual code from next time. Thanks again Mr. Dietmar, appriciate your help :)